# Angular 2: How to load TemplateRef from external file

Tags: templates, angular

I'm creating grid component with customizable cells config.
Currently, for being able to set custom cell component in cell config, I'm storing whole bunch of templates in view, like so:

```
<template let-row="row" #nameCell>
  <name-cell [row]="row"></name-cell>
</template>
```

Getting template in view and storing in grid config:

```
  @ViewChild('nameCell') nameCell: TemplateRef<any>;
  ...
  column.customCell = nameCell
```

And than using this template in grid cell:

```
    <template
      *ngIf="column.customCell"
      [ngTemplateOutlet]="column.customCell"
      [ngOutletContext]="{ row: row}">
    </template>
```

This works, but looks messy and dirty.
Is there way to load TemplateRef dynamically from external file?

Comment: In the following [link](https://www.dev6.com/Modal-Templates-in-Angular2-Part-3) there is a solution but if you ask me, I think it's better to use separate components and pass the needed data to it using a input, like [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child).

Comment: What did you end up doing? I want exactly the same thing for certain commonly used things where a component is too heavy.